# Multiple subtypes at same time?

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible, within Java generics, to store multiple subtypes at the same time?

I was under the impression when you declare your container, the generic parameter has to be concrete (rather than an interface or abstract superclass), so this only leaves using a non-abstract superclass?

Comment: If you have `List<A> listA;` and B and C inherits from A, then `listA` could have B and C objects inside.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza but A couldn't be an abstract class?

Comment: It's also important to note that generics in java is only a compile-time feature.  Due to type-erasure, the runtime is not aware of your generic types.  That's only there for compile-time type safety.

Comment: `A` could be an interface or a class (even an abstract class). If `B` and `C` inherits from A (by extend or implementing it, depending of A type), `List<A> listA` can have `B` and `C` objects.

Comment: Abstract Classes are allowed, too.

Comment: A simple test of a List<List> etc. would likely have answered this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this code sample will show you the basics about generics:

```
abstract class A {
    protected String s;
    //getters and setters...
}

class B extends A {
    public B() { s = "I'm B object"; }
}

class C extends A {
    public C() { s = "I'm C object"; }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
        listA.add(new B());
        listA.add(new C());
        List<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
        listB.add(new B());
        listB.add(new C()); //compile error: datatype mismatch

        printListA(listA);
        printListA(listB); //compile error: datatype mismatch
        printListAExtended(listA); //this compiles and executes right
        printListAExtended(listB); //this compiles and executes right
    }

    //this method must receive a List<A> object
    public static void printListA(List<A> listA) {
        for(A a : listA) {
            System.out.println(a.getS());
        }
    }

    //this method must receive a List<A or some class that implements A> object
    //that's why List<A>, List<B> or List<C> or any other List<anything implementing A>
    //can be passed here
    public static void printListAExtended(List<? extends A> listA) {
        for(A a : listA) {
            System.out.println(a.getS());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Abstract superclasses are allowed.

Assuming Shape is abstract and Rectangle and Circle extends it; the following code will compile.

```
List<Shape> shapeList = new ArrayList<Shape>();
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
Circle c = new Circle();
shapeList.add(r);
shapeList.add(c);

for (int i=0;i<shapeList.size();i++){
    shapeList.get(i).draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was under the impression when you declare your container, the
>   generic parameter has to be concrete (rather than an interface or
>   abstract superclass), so this only leaves using a non-abstract
>   superclass?

You are incorrect. The type in a type parameter can be any reference type. It could be a class, an interface, an abstract class, an array type, *whatever*. It could even be a type variable, i.e. you don't even know what type it is. It could also be an intersection of the above-mentioned types.